# How to expose C++ serialized data to python using boost_python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

We decided to expose one of our IPC (Inter Process Communication) modules written in C++ to python (I know, it's not the brightest idea). We use data packets that can be serialized and deserialized to/from `std::string` (behavior similar to Protocol Buffers, just not as efficient), so our IPC class returns and accepts `std::string` as well.

The problem with exposing that class to python is that `std::string` c++ type is converted to `str` python type, and in case the returned `std::string` consists of characters that cannot be decoded to `UTF-8` (which is most of the time) I get the `UnicodeDecodeError` exception.

I managed to find two workarounds (or even "solutions"?) for this problem, but I am not particularly happy with any of them.

This is my c++ code to reproduce `UnicodeDecodeError` problem and to try the solutions:

```
/*
 * boost::python string problem
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>

struct Packet {
    std::string serialize() const {
        char buff[sizeof(x_) + sizeof(y_)];
        std::memcpy(buff, &x_, sizeof(x_));
        std::memcpy(buff + sizeof(x_), &y_, sizeof(y_));
        return std::string(buff, sizeof(buff));
    }
    bool deserialize(const std::string& buff) {
        if (buff.size() != sizeof(x_) + sizeof(y_)) {
            return false;
        }
        std::memcpy(&x_, buff.c_str(), sizeof(x_));
        std::memcpy(&y_, buff.c_str() + sizeof(x_), sizeof(y_));
        return true;
    }
    // whatever ...
    int x_;
    float y_;
};

class CommunicationPoint {
public:
    std::string read() {
        // in my production code I read that std::string from the other communication point of course
        Packet p;
        p.x_ = 999;
        p.y_ = 1234.5678;
        return p.serialize();
    }
    std::vector<uint8_t> readV2() {
        Packet p;
        p.x_ = 999;
        p.y_ = 1234.5678;
        std::string buff = p.serialize();
        std::vector<uint8_t> result;
        std::copy(buff.begin(), buff.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
        return result;
    }
    boost::python::object readV3() {
        Packet p;
        p.x_ = 999;
        p.y_ = 1234.5678;
        std::string serialized = p.serialize();
        char* buff = new char[serialized.size()];  // here valgrind detects leak
        std::copy(serialized.begin(), serialized.end(), buff);
        PyObject* py_buf = PyMemoryView_FromMemory(
            buff, serialized.size(), PyBUF_READ);
        auto retval = boost::python::object(boost::python::handle<>(py_buf));
        //delete[] buff;  // if I execute delete[] I get garbage in python
        return retval;
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(UtfProblem) {
    boost::python::class_<std::vector<uint8_t> >("UintVec")
        .def(boost::python::vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<uint8_t> >());
    boost::python::class_<CommunicationPoint>("CommunicationPoint")
        .def("read", &CommunicationPoint::read)
        .def("readV2", &CommunicationPoint::readV2)
        .def("readV3", &CommunicationPoint::readV3);
}
```

It can be compiled with `g++ -g -fPIC -shared -o UtfProblem.so -lboost_python-py35 -I/usr/include/python3.5m/ UtfProblem.cpp` (in production we use CMake of course).

This is a short python script that loads my library and decodes the numbers:

```
import UtfProblem
import struct

cp = UtfProblem.CommunicationPoint()

#cp.read()  # exception

result = cp.readV2()
# result is UintVec type, so I need to convert it to bytes first
intVal = struct.unpack('i', bytes([x for x in result[0:4]]))
floatVal = struct.unpack('f', bytes([x for x in result[4:8]]))
print('intVal: {} floatVal: {}'.format(intVal, floatVal))

result = cp.readV3().tobytes()
intVal = struct.unpack('i', result[0:4])
floatVal = struct.unpack('f', result[4:8])
print('intVal: {} floatVal: {}'.format(intVal, floatVal))
```

In the first workaround instead of returning `std::string` I return `std::vector<unit8_t>`. It works OK, but I don't like the fact that it forces me to expose additional artificial python type `UintVec` that doesn't have any native support for the conversion to python `bytes`.

Second workaround is nice, because it exposes my serialized packet as a block of memory with native support for conversion to bytes, but it leaks the memory. I verified the memory leak using valgrind: `valgrind --suppressions=../valgrind-python.supp --leak-check=yes -v --log-file=valgrindLog.valgrind python3 UtfProblem.py` and apart from a lot of invalid reads (probably false positives) from python library it shows me

> 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost

in the line when I am allocating the memory for my buffer. If I delete the memory before returning from the function I will get some garbage in python.

### Question:

How can I appropriately expose my serialized data to python? In C++ to represent the array of bytes we usually use `std::string` or `const char*`, which unfortunately doesn't port to python in a nice way.

If my second workaround seems to be OK for you, how can I avoid the memory leak?

If exposing return value as `std::string` is in general OK, how can I avoid the `UnicodeDecodeError` ?

Additional info:

- g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
- Python 3.5.3
- boost 1.62

Comment: instead of a memory view item why not return a pythonic bytes object ?

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite , thanks, it works perfectly, much easier than I expected. When I looked for the solution on SO and python docs every approach was super complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [AntiMatterDynamite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9138208/antimatterdynamite) comment, returning pythonic `bytes` object (using Python API) works perfectly fine:

```
PyObject* read() {
    Packet p;
    p.x_ = 999;
    p.y_ = 1234.5678;
    std::string buff = p.serialize();
    return PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(buff.c_str(), buff.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define your own return type class in C++ and expose that using Boost Python.  You can have it implement the buffer protocol for example.  Then you'll have a regular C++ destructor which will be called at the appropriate time--you can even use a smart pointer inside the class to manage the lifetime of the allocated memory.

Once you've done that, the next question will be: why not just have the returned object expose properties to access the fields, without making the caller use `struct.unpack()`?  Then your calling code could be much simpler:

```
result = cp.readV5()
print('intVal: {} floatVal: {}'.format(result.x, result.y))
```

Comment: I cannot do that, because IPC doesn't know what type of object will be sent (only that it is represented by array of bytes). In the example I neglected many details, actually in our production code in the client side I can just do: `p = SomeSpecificPacket(); p.deserialize(ipc.read())`. Of course only if `read` function returns array of bytes :); Btw, comment from AntiMatterDynamite solves my problem.